# How do I programmatically add fields to Paragraph types?

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

I have one paragraph type of Product. and I have to add one field to paragraph product programmatically, how can I achive this.

```
function my_module_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $context){
  if ($element['#paragraph_type'] == 'products') {
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->info('debug');

<!-- add field here -->

  }
}
```

and other answer I found is

```
use Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph;

  $paragraph = Paragraph::load($paragraph_id);
  $paragraph->field_image[] = [
    'target_id' => $fid,
    'alt' => $alt,
    'title' => $title,
  ];
  $paragraph->save();
```

But in which function or preprocess I need to add above code?

Comment: Normally you go to the UI edit a paragraph type, add fields, save, export config, done. What are you trying to do here? And why don't you use the UI and export config as usual?

Comment: @leymannx I need to create one dropdown field in paragraph and options of that dropdown will be come from config file.

Comment: Then add the field from the UI and define an allowed values callback in a custom module.

Comment: @leymannx can you share link

Comment: check this out https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/automatically-provide-options-list-field-type-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

We cannot create a field to existing paragraph type using `hook_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter()`, because it will not create the field.  So the best way to add a custom field is using `hook_entity_base_field_info()`

In my case I need to create a text field in all my existing paragraph types and into the new paragraph which will be created in future so I used below code.

```
function hook_entity_base_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'paragraph') {
    $fields['field_parent_section_class'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Parent section class'))
      ->setDescription(t('Class for the parent section element( Add more than one class separated by space )'))
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', array(
        'settings' => array (
        'display_label' => TRUE
      )))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setSettings(array(
        'default_value' => '',
        'max_length' => 255,
        'persist_with_no_fields' => TRUE
      ));     
    return $fields;
  }
}
```